# Postgre or mysql id column auto increment

Tags: mysql, postgresql, unique, primary-key, ddl

I have a question about primary keys in postgre or mysql.

So:

In mongodb the ids are not integers, they are some unique values like "507f191e810c19729de860ea". This helps when you want to synchronize records from multiple ids. They will never match (or the chances are little). So I can get a record from one database and insert it in my database without conflicts in the id primary key constraint.

So my question is there are similar functionality in Postgre SQL or MySQL databases.

I know I can generate the id with php/nodejs/python but I prefer to use something automatic and simple from the database itself.

I can make my procedure/function in the database but I avoid that - I want the database to handle this automatically (like mongodb does it).

Are there any downsides of this approach?

Comment: Are you looking for [UUIDs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-uuid.html)?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid for mysql. but you shoudn't ignore auto_increment.

Comment: Thanks, I like UUIDS but when I insert i should pass UUID() function, can the database generate the id itself, like if I dont pass "id" in the insert query it generates automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can generate UUID.

First, you need to make sure you have the extension installed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

and then use the `uuid_generate_v4` function to generate a `UUID`. If you don't want to have to remember to insert it every time, you can just define it as the default value of your primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
  -- other columns as needed...
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was i looking for. So If i am correct: If i query "INSERT INTO BOOKS(title) VALUES('book1'); if i do it with regular BIGINT it will set id=1 (for empty table) and in this case it will automaticall generates UUID, correct? Thanks

Comment: In this case you'll get an autogenerated UUID. For a `bigint` you'll get the default of `null` unless you explicitly specify some other default or value. For a `serial` column you'll get the default of `1` as you suggested.

Comment: So it will work the same way like id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, but instead of integers it will save UUIDS. Last question: is this functionality exists in MySql?

Comment: @user2693928 MySQL doesn't have a built-in `uuid` type. Since MySQL 8.0 there are some functions to generate UUIDs, but you'll have to use them as `varchar`s, or convert them to `binary`s yourself. See [this blogpost](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/) from the developer team for details.

Comment: Ok, thank you, are there downsides to using UUIDS instead of bigint primary keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SERIAL** as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id SERIAL
);
```

This is like a auto increment in SQL.

Comment: I take it this is postgresql?

Comment: "SERIAL is an alias for BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE." so if it is integer 2 databases key will conflict, is that correct?

Comment: @user2693928 yes, that's correct. `serial` is a good way to generate uniqueness in a table, but not a great way to generate uniqueness cross tables or databases.

Comment: Actually, "SERIAL" is an alias for "INTEGER" with a sequence attached. "BIGSERIAL" will be a "BIGINT" with a sequence. One is 4 bytes, the other consumes 8 bytes.